# Product Order wont Ship

Tags: orders, shipping

This is in Magento 1.9.x

I am trying to ship a test order and failing miserably. Ive managed to ship other test orders fine, but this one gets to this page, and gives me nowhere to progress forward or no indication of what is wrong - can anyone point me in the right direction please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small hint to let you know something is wrong; the page seems to end after the 'Items to Ship' fieldset starts. So let's break out Aoe_TemplateHints to see what's going on at that point;

[image: Aoe_TemplateHints]

There's a block called order_items that should be there. This is also the block that should show you the shipment comments and the Submit Shipment button.

In `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/form.phtml` on line 80 you'll find;

```
<?php echo $this->getItemsHtml() ?>
```

This in turn (in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Shipment_Create_Form`) runs;

```
return $this->getChildHtml('order_items');
```

This block is defined in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml` on line 297;

```
<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_shipment_create_form" name="form" template="sales/order/shipment/create/form.phtml">
```

It looks like this block isn't set at all, or the template that is being called is throwing an error, since it's not showing at all.

So check whether the layout file and the template files are okay and see if there are any errors in var/log/error.log or your PHP log file that might have something to do with this.